# PNG attachment downloads corrupted on some systems

Tags: apache, perl, download, attachment

I am trying to serve a PNG file as an attachment.  This is working fine on my CentOS 8 development machine, but when I deploy it to a RedHat 7 machine the file has extra bytes in the downloaded file.  For example, viewing the PNG file in an emacs buffer, the original file shows:

```
\211PNG^M
```

but the downloaded file shows

```
\302\211PNG^M
```

and there are \302 entries throughout the downloaded file.

Again, this corruption occurs only on the RedHat 7 machines.

I check the file byte count on the server process and it has the correct value.  It appears these \302 entries are being added by the server.

The server process is a Perl script, and I'm using a regular print statement to output the image file contents.

Answer (score 2):

The UTF-8 encoding of Code Point 0211 (0x89) is 0302 0211 (0xC2 89). You are encoding the image using UTF-8 for some reason. Don't :)

Comment: Thanks ikegami.  I'll investigate.